# get href attribute on jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got troubles, tried everything but variable always undefined =/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#show").load("index.php");
        });
        $(document).on('click', ' a[href]', function (e) {
            var a_href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            alert ("Href is: "+a_href); //just for test
           $("#show").load(a_href);
           return false;
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="one.php">One</a>
<br>
<a href="two.php">two</a>

    <div id="show"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I actually want links to be taken from #show div and replace show div load after it without changing the link or reloading the page, the links are generated in php and always change this is why i cant have static links.

Comment: You seem to be looking for an anchor tag inside the anchor tag you clicked, try removing the `.find('a')`

Answer (score 2):

You already select the link with `.on('click', ' a[href]',` so `$(this).find('a')` is looking for a link that's a descendant of the link that you clicked on, which doesn't exist.

Change:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href')
```

to

```
$(this).attr('href') // jQuery
```

or

```
this.href // plain JavaScript as noted by epascarello
```

Comment: 15 seconds faster than me.

Comment: How can i set it up working links only from #show div ?

Comment: It should be noted that `this.href`returns the full/resolved path, but `$(this).attr('href')` or `this.getAttribute('href')` returns the original attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
  .... your code
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
  .... your code
```